# Chiral WZW term for Hadron Supersymmetry?

Tags: mesons, baryons

Remarkably, an approximate supersymmetry not in the color- but in the flavor-sector is experimentally observed: [hadron supersymmetry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hadron%20supersymmetry), relating mesons (the bosons) to baryons (the fermions).

The most developed formalism for describing hadron supersymmetry in detail seems to [holographic light front QCD](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/holographic+light+front+QCD), where meson/baryon supersymmetry is witnessed by the fact that ordinary QCD in light front quantization becomes supersymmetric quantum mechanics on the light cone.

On the other hand, the most developed formalism for describing mesons by themselves is any version of effective [quantum hadrodynamics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/chiral%20perturbation%20theory) (chiral perturbation theory, vector dominance, ...), where the chiral anomaly is witnessed by a [chiral WZW term](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/chiral%20perturbation%20theory#WZWTermOfChiralPerturbationTheoryReferences) in the meson fields.

**Question**: Does anyone develop and discuss the combination of these two?

There ought to be a flavor-supersymmetric  version of quantum hadrodynamics (of chiral perturbation theory, ...) which adjoins to the mesons, typically regarded as gauge bosons of chiral "hidden local symmetry", fermionic super-partners identified as baryons. Does anyone discuss the chiral anomaly WZW term of such a hadron-supersymmetrized theory?

Or else, why not?

Comment: WZW not mentioned, but https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.12866 tries to embed LF hQCD in a nonstandard string theory